# How to Make preg_match array data useful on Screen

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I've used preg_match() to check a string coming from an XML feed (ie: $resp = simplexml_load_file($API);) which returns upwards of 1000 items and with preg_match I've extracted a bit of data from each item which is stored in $matches but I don't know how to make use of what preg_match has stored in $matches

Here's what I've got and what I've tried.

Note: I have print_r($matches); just so I could see the results while modifying the preg pattern.

```
    $matches;

        preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{5,19} ?-?\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d?*(?=\s|$)/', $Apples, $matches);

            print_r($matches);

/*Note: $matches returns an array as such: Array ( [0] => Stringdata ) Array ( [0] => moreStringdata ) Array ( [0] => stillmoreStringData ) Array ( [0] => evenmoreStringData ) Array ( [0] => moreStringDataStill )... and I'm just wanting to use array[0] from each in the $results string which is output to the screen */  

    $results.= "<div class='MyClass'><a href=\"$link\"><img src=\"$linktopicture\"></a><a href=\"$linktopageaboutapples\">$matches</a></div>";
```

I Also tried $matches(), $matches[] and $matches[0] in the $results string but nothing works and since I don't know much about using arrays I thought I'd ask so if anyone wouldn't mind setting me straight with what is probably very elementrary I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all in advance.

Comment: ANd what is the contents of `$matches`?

Comment: Please add to your code sample the definition of $Pattern (and correct the typo) and add the output of print_r($matches) to the question.

Comment: @Arkanon Why would anyone need the definition of Pattern? (Except my competition) I just need to know how to use the data stored in $matches.

Comment: @Arkanon typo corrected and sample of $matches added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read the [preg_match doc page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to understand the way the function works.

Firstly, check to see whether preg_match returns `1` (which means the value in `$Apples` does match the pattern) or `0` (which means `$Apples` does not match the pattern) or `FALSE` (which means an error occurred).

Assuming `1` is returned, then $matches[0] will contain the entire portion of the $Apples string which matches the pattern. If you have capture groups then the portion of that match which falls within the first capture group will be found in $matches[1], second in $matches[2] and so on.

If you can't share your regex pattern it's not possible to see whether your pattern contains any capture groups, so let's use this example:

```
preg_match("/key:([A-Z]+);value:([0-9]+)/", "key:ERRORCODE;value:500", $matches);
```

Now `$matches[0]` should contain "key:ERRORCODE;value:500" because the entire string matches the pattern, and `$matches[1]` should contain "ERRORCODE", and `$matches[2]` should contain "500", because these portions fit the patterns in the capture groups of the full pattern.

Comment: Hi again @Arkanon, Iv'e read the preg_match document you provided (BEFORE You provided it) and I still don't understand a LOT. Sorry about not sharing my pattern. I will edit my initial question to use a pattern SIMILAR to what I am looking extracting, however, I have no idea about: "key:ERRORCODE;value:500" Gimme just a sec to update my initial question.

Comment: I updated the pattern and the array data sample. I presumed Array ( [0] => data ) Array ( [0] => moredata )...etc would have been sufficient. My Bad on not being clearer

Comment: Surely the data stored in $matches can be used for more than to merely look at via print_r()?????? (I Hope) as I used preg_match to extract small bits from the strings which I want to inject into the $results string